# Read override property attribute

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, custom-attributes

I have overridden property in class and would like to read custom attribute values, but it do not work. Could anyone explain why it is not working and how to solve the problem?

```
    public class Validator
    {


        [Serializable]
        public class CollectionAttribute : Attribute
        {
            public virtual string[] Data { get; set; }
            public string Default;
        }
}

 class Helpers
    {

        public static MemberInfo GetMemberInfo<T, TU>(Expression<Func<T, TU>> expression)
        {
            var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (member != null)
                return member.Member;

            throw new ArgumentException("Expression is not a member access", "expression");
        }

        public static string GetName<T, TU>(Expression<Func<T, TU>> expression)
        {
            return GetMemberInfo(expression).Name;
        }

        public static string GetCollection<T, TU>(Expression<Func<T, TU>> expression)
        {
            var attribute = (Validator.CollectionAttribute[])GetMemberInfo(expression).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Validator.CollectionAttribute), true);
            return string.Join(",", attribute[0].Data); 
        }
    }
```

Do not work.

```
 public class TestClass:TestBaseClass
    {
        [Validator.Collection(Data = new[] { "doc", "docx", "dot", "dotx", "wpd", "wps", "wri" })]
        public override string InputFormat { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestBaseClass
    {
        public virtual string InputFormat { get; set; }
    }

Helpers.GetCollection((TestClass p) => p.InputFormat)
//The attribute variable in GetCollection method always null. It seems code looks for atribute in Base class.
```

Works fine.

```
 public class TestClass
    {
        [Validator.Collection(Data = new[] { "doc", "docx", "dot", "dotx", "wpd", "wps", "wri" })]
        public override string InputFormat { get; set; }
    }

Helpers.GetCollection((TestClass p) => p.InputFormat)
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaring type of `InputFormat` is `TestBaseClass` which doesn't have that attribute. And the `PropertyInfo` which returned is for the declaring type, not for the actual type of the parameter.

What you have to do, is retrieve the actual type of the expression's parameter, and then return the `PropertyInfo` for that type.

```
public static MemberInfo GetMemberInfo<T, TU>(Expression<Func<T, TU>> expression)
{
    var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (member != null)
    {
        // Getting the parameter's actual type, and retrieving the PropertyInfo for that type.
        return expression.Parameters.First().Type.GetProperty(member.Member.Name);
    }

    throw new ArgumentException("Expression is not a member access", "expression");
}
```